# Short and simple way to send a syslog message to a remote machine?

Tags: c, sockets, syslog

I have a C program that is currently logging events via syslog, after calling openlog to specify a program name.

The meat of my program that logs events to syslog is just three lines:

```
openlog(program_name, 0, facility);
syslog(log_level|facility,"%s\n",message);
closelog()
```

However, there are situations in my program where I should be sending the syslog event to a remote machine instead of logging locally, as the syslog function ordinarily does.  What I'd like to do is optionally supply some other information to the function containing the above lines, such as a host (and optionally, a port), and whether to use udp or tcp, and if such information is present, send the syslog event to another machine via the rsyslog protocol to that machine.

What I categorically do *NOT* want to do is have to change any of the configuration files for the syslog daemon.  I simply wish to, under program control, be able to send the same messages to another machine's syslog that would have otherwise shown up locally using the above three lines.

The only way I've been able to verify for sure I would be able to do this under program control is to construct a message manually that conforms to RFC 5424, and send it over a socket connection manually.  Will I have to write the code to do all of this from scratch myself, or is there some existing facility out there (open source) that will do what I need?

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/misc-utils/logger.c. It's the source to `logger`

Answer (score 0):

Not in C but I used this to test my syslog server...

> echo "$(TZ=UTC date +%FT%T.%NZ) $(uname -n) subsystem: hello" | socat -d -d - udp-sendto:syslog-server:514